# <br> vs. <BR> with str_replace in PHP

Tags: php, html, tags, str-replace, mailto

I'm trying to do a str_replace on a  text block like below that is in variable $who:

```
Acme Corporation
<BR><br>Accounting Dept
<BR><br>123 Sesame St.
<BR><br>New York, NY 10021
<BR><br>(123)456-7890
```

I'm using `str_replace` below to remove the `<br>` and `<BR>` tags:

```
$who = str_replace("<br>","%0D%0A",html_entity_decode($who));
$who = str_replace("<BR>","%0D%0A",html_entity_decode($who));
```

My problem is that the end result does not get rid of 
 tags. The output looks like this:

```
    Acme Corporation
<BR>Accounting Dept
<BR>123 Sesame St.
<BR>New York, NY 10021
<BR>(123)456-7890
```

I didn't think capitalization would be a problem for `str_replace()`. I've tried `pre_replace()` as well and used both double and single quotes. I'm inserting this into the body of `mailto` link and html tags need to go. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I am trying to remove all br and BR tags from the string in variable $who. I need to replace them with %0D%0A. This is because the resulting string is being inserted into the body of a mailto. Here is the full code:

```
//GetValues where CCDLookUps were unnecessary
$who = CCDLookUp("data", "template", "template_name = 'poscc_header'", $db);
$terms = $payment1->pterms->GetValue(); 
$buyer = $users->uName->GetValue();
$comp = $users->company->GetValue();
$bEmail = $users->uMail->GetValue();    
$totSold = $invoices1->total->GetValue();
$tot = $invoices1->total->GetValue();
$payamt = $payment1->amount->GetValue();
$seq = $payment1->seq->GetValue();

//correct Money output
$totSold = money_format('$%i', $totSold);   
$price = money_format('$%i', $price);   
$tax = money_format('$%i', $tax);
$ship = money_format('$%i', $ship); 
$tot = money_format('$%i', $tot);   
$payamt = money_format('$%i', $payamt);

//builds header and header template     

$who = str_replace("<br>","%0D%0A",html_entity_decode($who));
//$who = str_replace("<BR>",'%0D%0A',html_entity_decode($who));
$bodymsg = $who;


//main body     
$bodymsg .= "%0D%0A%0D%0AConfirmation: ".$order_id."%0D%0AOrder Date: ".$odate."%0D%0ADelivery: ".$deltype;
$bodymsg .= "%0D%0ATerms: ".$terms."%0D%0ASeller ID: ".$sellerID."%0D%0ABuyer: ".$buyer."%0D%0A             ".$comp;
$bodymsg .= "%0D%0A%0D%0A";
$bodymsg .= "%0D%0ATotal Items Sold: ".$totSold."%0D%0AQty: ".$qty."%0D%0AProduct: ".$prod."%0D%0APrice: ".$price;
$bodymsg .= "%0D%0ATax: ".$tax."%0D%0AShipping: ".$ship."%0D%0ATotal: ".$tot."%0D%0A%0D%0APayment Amount: ".$payamt;
$bodymsg .= "%0D%0ASeq: ".$seq."%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0ACustomer Copy%0D%0A%0D%0ANo Refunds/No Exchanges%0D%0A";
$bodymsg .= "Thank you";

//place into message and set to link        
$mlto = "mailto:".$bEmail."&subject=Receipt%20For%20Order%23%20".$order_id."&body=".$bodymsg;
$Page->eLink->SetValue($mlto);
```

Comment: you need to edit this so we can see the tags

Comment: Works correctly here: http://rextester.com/STI84360

Comment: Hey Marcin! How's that new username working out?

Comment: question is: how is mail being handled and why are HTML markup tags get into the picture in the first place?

Comment: can any one tell me what "%0D%0A" are suppose to be?

Comment: That would be a line-feed and carriage return @rtfm, seeing as how you didn't rtfm

Comment: @Barmar *Right*. To which [I asked for clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44639882/br-vs-br-with-str-replace-in-php#comment76265864_44639882) and voted as unclear.

Comment: so why not use \r and \n  like the rest of us?

Comment: *"I'm inserting this into the body of mailto link"* - again; question's unclear. Post your full code. This makes my vote to close valid. Least "that" holds water.

Comment: Since the OP is not responding @rtfm your guess would be as good as any.

Comment: :-) *mailto*? people still use that? what about a web based form?

Comment: @rtfm Since he's putting them into a URL, they need to be url-encoded. Although the best way would be to call `urlencode()` on the final result.

Comment: I've updated the question. The mail would be handled by whatever mail handler the user was using. This is to be used to send a receipt for a purchase. The HTML tags are there because the $who variable is being pulled from a database that would normally use the string on a webpage. Mailto links cannot use HTML in the body attribute, but "%0D%0A" does the line feed and carriage return. Also \n and \r is PHP code and would not work in the mailto body attribute. Can't use anything that would add a library or class, so web based forms are out.

Comment: urlencode() fixed this problem. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $result = preg_replace("~<br>~i", "\r\n", $who);
?>
```

The `i` option let the `preg_replace()` function work case-insensitive, so it should replace `<br>` and `<BR>`.
To use this in an `mailto:` link a possible way could be to use `urlencode()`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your question you want to replace the 
 tag with new line so you have to use \n which refer to new line in your code and it will be as the following

```
 <?php
        $who="Acme Corporation
        <BR><br>Accounting Dept
        <BR><br>123 Sesame St.
        <BR><br>New York, NY 10021
        <BR><br>(123)456-7890";
        $who = str_replace("<br>","\n",html_entity_decode($who));
        echo $who;
        ?>
```